# Чат для переписки пользователей на сайте

Tags: mysql, sql

Всем доброго времени суток!
Стоит задача сделать чат переписки, пользователи могут общаться между собой как на странице товара, так и в личном кабинете. Будет много пользователей и много сообщений.

Необходимо сделать 2 таблицы в mysql - "Чатов" и "Сообщений".

Вопрос: Как лучше сделать эти две таблицы? В какой что хранить чтоб это было грамотно и не тормозило функционал?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете сделать таблицу `chat` :

```
chat_id(INT), author_id(INT), recipient_id(INT), product_id(INT)
```

таблицу `chat_message`:

```
message_id(INT), chat_id(INT), author_message_id(INT), message(TEXT), date_added(DATETIME), status(INT)
```